# Inject bean in a plugin MyBatis has a null value

Tags: java, cdi, mybatis

I am using CDI (Weld ) in a web application developed in JSF and MyBatis on a Tomcat application server.

When I inject a bean into a plugin of MyBatis, the injected bean always has a null value, instead of injecting the correct instance of the bean.

What am I doing wrong?

Regards

```
import es.metadata.metaqualitas.web.SessionBean;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.apache.ibatis.executor.Executor;
import org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Interceptor;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Intercepts;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Signature;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.ResultHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.RowBounds;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Intercepts({
    @Signature(type = Executor.class, method = "query", args = {MappedStatement.class, Object.class, RowBounds.class, ResultHandler.class}),
    @Signature(type = Executor.class, method = "update", args = {MappedStatement.class, Object.class})
})
public class ExamplePlugin implements Interceptor, Serializable {

    //log has a ApplicationScope
    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    //sessionBean has a SessionScoped        
    @Inject
    private SessionBean sessionBean;

    @Override
    public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        //log and sessionBean are always worth null and launch NullPointerException
        log.info(sessionBean.getUsuario());        
        return invocation.proceed();
    }

    @Override
    public Object plugin(Object target) {
        return Plugin.wrap(target, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperties(Properties properties) {    
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class LoggerProducer {

    @Produces  
    public Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {        
        return Logger.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());  
    }
}

-------------------------------------------
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {

    private String usuario;

    public String getUsuario(){
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario){
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        usuario = "Pedro";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a beans.xml?

Comment: Yes. I have a beans.xml and the beans are injected correctly in the rest of the Web application.

Comment: I think injection in plain classes like the MyBatis interceptors just does not work. I tried googling for this but did not find anything (neither saying it works nor does not work). Using a beanmanager to retrieve them programmatically might be a solution

Comment: can you show server logs to show weld is deployed correctly?